# Web SQL results invalid order as i intended

Tags: database, sqlite, synchronous

I have 5 Questions in database table 
1 textbox
2 dropdown
3 dropdown
4 textbox
5 textbox

but when I finish transactions it shows with invalid order like
1 textbox
4 textbox
5 textbox
then
2 dropdown
3 dropdown

it should be shown as above with correct order

in getDropdown function to get all options item

what's i'm doing wrong, Anyone can help? please,

//main function initially call to get all question

```
function showQuestions(){
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function(tx, result) {
          dataset = result.rows;

        for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {
          item = dataset.item(i);
          if(item['ANS_TYPE'] == "dropdown"){
              getDropdown(item['QU_MESSAGE'],item['QU_ID']);
          }
          if(item['ANS_TYPE'] == "textbox"){
              getTextbox(item['QU_MESSAGE']);
          }
        }//for loop
      });//execute
    });//transaction
}//end function

function getTextbox(question){
    $('#elements').append('<div data-role="fieldcontain">'
                        + '<label for="textinput1">'
                        + question
                        + '</label><br /><br />'
                        + '<input name="" id="textinput1" placeholder="" value="" type="text">'
                        + '<br /><br /><hr></div>').trigger('create');
}
function getDropdown(question,qu_id){
    var options = ''; option = '';
    options += '<div data-role="fieldcontain">'
            + '<label for="selectmenu1">'
            + question
            + '</label><br /><br />';
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql(selectChoiceStatement, [qu_id], function(tx, result) {
        dataset = result.rows;
        option = '';
        for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {
            item = dataset.item(i);
            var data = item['CH_MSG'];
            option += '<option>'+data+'</option>';
        }
        options += '<select id="selectmenu1" name="">'+option+'</select>'
                 + '<br /><br /><hr></div>';
        $('#elements').append(options).trigger('create');
        });

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback function of `executeSql` is called asynchronously.

You should probably create the `<select>` immediately and add the `<option>`s later.